# "yield" in Python

Tags: python, iteration, generator, yield

I have a function called **x** that produces a generator like this:

```
a = 5
def x():
    global a
    if a == 3:
        raise Exception("Stop")
    a = a - 1
    yield a
```

Then in the python shell I call that function like this:

```
>>> print x().next()
>>> 4
>>> print x().next()
>>> 3
>>> print x().next()
>>> <python-input-112-f3c02bba26c8> in x()
          2     global a
          3     if a == 3:
    ----> 4         raise Exception
          5     a = a - 1
          6     yield a

    Exception:
```

However, when I call that function and assign it to a variable, it behaves differently:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = x()
>>> print b.next()
>>> 4
>>> print b.next()
>>> ----> 1 b.next()
    StopIteration:
```

How is that even possible? Shouldn't it print out **3** and raise StopIteration in the next iteration?

PS: I know that when I first call the function, **the body does not run, just produces a generator**. The point I didn't understand is that what changes if I call and assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your first example, you were creating a **new** generator each time:

```
x().next()
```

This starts the generator *from the top*, so the first statement. When `a == 3`, the exception is raised, otherwise the generator just yields and *pauses*.

When you assigned your generator later on, the global `a` started at `5`, the code then *continued* from where it left of until it ends or comes across another `yield` statement, then *ended*. When a generator function ends, it raises `StopIteration`.

Let's break this down into steps:

1. `a = 5`.
2. You create new generator and call `.next()` on it. The following code is executed:

   ```
   global a
   if a == 3:  # False
       raise Exception("Stop")
   a = a - 1   # a is now 4
   yield a
   ```

   The generator is paused on the last line, and `4` is yielded.
3. You create a new generator and call `.next()` on it. `a` is `4` at the start:

   ```
   global a
   if a == 3:  # False
       raise Exception("Stop")
   a = a - 1   # a is now 3
   yield a
   ```

   The generator is paused on the last line, and `3` is yielded.
4. You create a new generator and call `.next()` on it. `a` is `3` at the start:

   ```
   global a
   if a == 3:  # True
       raise Exception("Stop")
   ```

   An exception is raised.
5. You set `a = 5` again.
6. You create a new generator, store a reference in `b` and call `.next()` on it. The following code is executed:

   ```
   global a
   if a == 3:  # False
       raise Exception("Stop")
   a = a - 1   # a is now 4
   yield a
   ```

   The generator is paused on the last line, and `4` is yielded.
7. You call `.next()` **again** on the same, existing generator referenced by `b`. The code *resumes* at the paused point.

   The function has no more code at that point, and returns. `StopIteration` is raised.

If you were to use a *loop* instead, you'd see the difference better:

```
>>> def looping(stop):
...    for i in looping(stop):
...        yield i
...
>>> looping(3).next()
0
>>> looping(3).next()
0
```

Note how each time I create a new generator, the loop starts from the beginning. Store a reference however, and you'll notice it continue instead:

```
>>> stored = looping(3)
>>> stored.next()
0
>>> stored.next()
1
>>> stored.next()
2
>>> stored.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

During the loop, each time the `yield` expression is executed, the code is *paused*; calling `.next()` continues the function where it left of the previous time.

The `StopIteration` exception is entirely normal; it is how generators communicate that they are done. A `for` loop looks for this exception to end the loop:

```
>>> for i in looping(3):
...     print i
... 
0
1
2
```

Comment: OMG, how could you write all this text in 3 minutes?

Comment: @Matthias: I am a fast typer, but you also get up to 5 minutes grace time, to add to a post without the last edited time updating.

Answer (score 0):

You've not quite got how yield works. I think this example might help:

```
>>> def a():
...    for x in range(5):
...        yield x
...
>>> a()
<generator object a at 0xb7f0a9b4>
>>> list(a())
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You normally want to use yield inside a loop, and it has the very distinct behavior of returning a value, then later resuming the loop.

If your example, x always returns a generator that will produce one item only. In your first example, you are calling x multiple times, so you get multiple results. In your second example, where you assign it to a variable, you are only calling it once, so you only get one result.

Also, you should not usually use a global variable in the way you have done.

Paul